# inserting special characters like alpha,beta in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I insert **alpha,beta,delta** into a **MySQL** database through php script?

I want to save my subject codes to my db table using these special characters.

Example subject code `CSC113α`.

Comment: You need to use nvarchar datatype to insert special characters into your database.

Comment: The type nvarchar is TransactSQL / MS-SQL specific.

Comment: I can't parse those characters through a php script????that's the problem,,,

Answer (score 1):

From [this website:](http://forums.asp.net/t/1434051.aspx/1)

```
Declare @t table( id int, txt nvarchar(20))
Insert Into @t Values (1, N'αβγδ')
Insert Into @t Values (2, nchar(945)+nchar(946)+nchar(947)+nchar(948))
```

So, just make this into PHP, and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

Set the text collation of the field you are trying to insert to, to UTF8 and try to insert the special character again.

```
ALTER TABLE `table_name`
MODIFY COLUMN `column_name` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;
```

Comment: The characters should go through as you send them. If you are calling them back and they look funny, you can set your browser to show them correctly by adding this somewhere on your web page: <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

Comment: How are you connecting to the database? You can set the charset in the connection. Different methods (mysqli, pdo have different ways to do so)